# Are These Parts compatible?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I have never assembled a PC before, although I have taken an old one apart and replaced a few parts in others here and there so I have (very) limited experience. I have been looking to make a pc and here are the parts I might buy:

- Foxconn P45AL Intel P45 (Socket 775) DDR2 Motherboard (with onboard sound I believe)
- Gigabyte GeForce GTX 460 OC 768MB GDDR5 PCI-Express Graphics Card
- Already have 2 1gb sticks of dual channel DDR2 memory
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 LGA775 'Yorkfield' 2.66GHz 4MB-cache Processor
- Samsung SpinPoint F3 1TB SATA-II 32MB Cache Hard Drive
- Antec Dark Fleet Series DF10 Gaming Enclosure – Black
- I already have monitor, mouse, keyboard and DVD/CD drive
- Akasa Freedom Power 1000W Modular Power Supply

I have never done this before so feel free to laugh at me for getting something obvious wrong, forgetting a vital component etc. but is all of this compatible? And have I gone overkill on the PSU, if so, please recommend one. Thanks in advance, ell.

**EDIT:** Added PSU which I forgot to mention

**EDIT:** I would be using this to surf the internet, write e-mails, chat, word process, play games such as team fortress 2 & spring rts (at highest graphics hopefully), some 3d modelling in blender, some opengl programming, and image editing in GIMP.

Comment: WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY on earth an LGA 775 ? Heavens no!

Comment: I'm new with this! Whats wrong with LGA 775's?

Comment: they've reached end of life! ALso - you should mention your what your usage will be like

Comment: I'm guessing you chose based on price?  LGA775 is REALLY OLD, you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parts should all be compatible, although you are going to be CPU-constrained for graphics (i.e. the CPU will not allow the GPU to perform to its full potential).  However, if you are going to be playing older games, it should be fine.

I do not see a PSU listed, but I would budget at least 500W for this (I'm not familiar with the GTX460's power requirements, but I imagine it's north of 110W).

You might consider going with 4 GB of RAM instead of 2 GB as well (budget-permitting, of course).

Comment: So I guess my 1000W PSU is way overkill. I didn't know what to have so I thought, better safe than sorry! What CPU could you recommend? or what clock speed/cache/other stats would you say I would need?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no such thing as too big a PSU...however, you should buy something that is more name brand such as Corsair or Antec.

Comment: A 1000W PSU is probably overkill for this rig.  You'd be better off putting the money into current gen motherboard+CPU+RAM.  So, wait a week and pick up an LGA1155 rig.

Answer (score 2):

Yes those parts are all compatible. The PSU for that system is definitely overkill. I would recommend going with a branded 500W PSU

Comment: He's not asking for a hardware recommendation (which is off topic per the FAQ), he wants to know about compatibility.

Comment: @ Daniel Beck - After everyone suggesting (sensibly) not to go for socket 775, I thought I would make a reasonable suggestion as to a more reasonable setup. Keep your knickers on.